# What does this notation mean: $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, notation

I have come across this excercise:

> Find all $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $x^6+x^3f''(x)=f(x^3)+x^3$.

What is the meaning of this notation: $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: It's a string of symbols each with well known meanings. What in this string of symbols troubles you exactly?

Comment: This should be explained in any book that contains such an exercise. There isn't much point skipping ahead in such a case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ simply means that $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$. That is:
$$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots + a_1x + a_0$$
where each $a_i$ is in $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

It means that $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ whose coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$.